# How to make bipolar supply -2.5v to +2.5v from unipolar supply?

Tags: power-supply

I need a regulated bipolar supply for precision adc. It should have two fixed outputs: +2.5v and -2.5v. How to build such supply using unipolar supply with voltage 5v or higher?

Comment: Many ways. Are the +2.5 and -2.5 common ground with the 5V? How accurate/stable/low-noise do they have to be? How much current is required on each supply?

Comment: @spehro-pefhany Perfectly it should be isolated (no common ground), as stable as possible, low drift with temperature and low noise as possible. Supply will power only the ADC which analog circuitry consumes aprox 2 mA. Can you list the possibilites?

Comment: Most stable as possible- in that case, I would recommend a [Josephson Junction primary standard](http://www.hypres.com/products/voltage-standard/).

Comment: Would a rail splitter work? This will give you a 2.5V reference exactly between the 5V supply and GND. You can then drive the ADC from that, using GND as the negative voltage reference.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's Andy & Olin's role to be sarcastic, obstructive, misleading, unconstructive and newcomer unfriendly. You have better things to do with your giftings. (Your task here is not done .... Your mission should you choose to accept it.... these are not the ... Hi ho Silver. Away!

Comment: If 5V is accurate then a 2.5V precision shunt regulatot drawing > I_max_ADC will (probably) do what you want simply.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon why how very rude LOL

Answer (score 1):

Make two 2.5V supply from two 5V supplies by voltage divider(2 resistors probably the high resisting ones) and [voltage follower with Op Amp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Voltage_buffer_examples)... and connect them to get split supplies...

Comment: To be more precise I have one 5V (+/-10%) supply. Firstly I want it to provide isolated 3.3V for MCU and ADC digital circuitry. Secondly I need isolated +2.5V and -2.5V for ADC analog circuitry, plus isolated virtual ground for sensor connected to ADC input. Voltage divider / rail splitter plus some isolated DC/DC converters and LDOs could work. Anyone knows more elegant solution?